# How can I call Screen Time by setting from my app at iOS12

Tags: ios

I want to call screen time setting when screentime can stop my app by schedule.

. My app is a form of data transfer between devices, but may be limited in some way, such as screen time. That's why. If that happens, the app has to stop and we want to tell the user why it stopped. Basically, I could confirm that the screen time was to stop the application, so in such a case, I would like to have the screen time of the iOS setting screen open from my application and check the contents. However, I can not find a way to call Screetime in iOS settings. Do you have a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can suggest to use Timer instead if you just wanna stop the app after an interval of time end

```
var timer: Timer!
```

You can then create that timer and tell it to execute after 1 hour (3600 seconds), like this:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3600, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimedCodeToCloseApp), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

The `runTimedCodeToCloseApp` selector means that the timer will call a method named `runTimedCodeToCloseApp()` after an hour, so you'll need to replace that method name with whatever you want to call – and don’t forget to mark it using `@objc`.

Important note: because your object has a property to store the timer, and the timer calls a method on the object, you have a strong reference cycle that means neither object can be freed. To fix this, make sure you invalidate the timer when you're done with it (when you call your method `runTimedCodeToCloseApp()` ), such as when your view is about to disappear:

```
timer.invalidate()
```

If you want to make a timer that execute a method after every hour change `repeats: false` to `repeats: true`

Hope that may help someone.

Comment: thank you for answering.
That is one way.

My app is a form of data transfer between devices, but may be limited in some way, such as screen time.
That's why. If that happens, the app has to stop and we want to tell the user why it stopped.
Basically, I could confirm that the screen time was to stop the application, so in such a case, I would like to have the screen time of the iOS setting screen open from my application and check the contents.
However, I can not find a way to call Screetime in iOS settings.

Do you have a good idea?